# Two divs floated left & right whats going on

Tags: html, css

So I have been working on a site of mine, and I have been having an issue with
two floated tags, being side by side, maybe I'm just tired but I cant figure out
why its not working right now.

the page in question is http://feelclix.com/index.php?view=prices the top 2
banners are not floating right I know its something small I am missing but I
cant put a finger on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `menu` height css is too tall. You've got it as `80px`. You can set it as `auto` and you'll have your divs line up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after, I had an open tag somewhere, I did however change the height.